# alternatives to PeekNamePipe() with anonymous pipe -- WIN32

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc, pipe

I have a program that launch another console program as its child process and communicate with it using anonymous pipe. I redirected both its stdin and stdout. The pseudocode is like:

```
// Create pipes for stdin and stdout
CreatePipe(&std_in_rd, &std_in_wr, NULL, 0);
CreatePipe(&std_out_rd, &std_out_wr, NULL, 0);

// redirection
startup_info.hStdOutput = std_out_wr;
startup_info.hStdInput = std_in_rd;

// create the process
CreateProcess(...);

// send command to the child process.
WriteFile(hWriteStdin, ...);

// receive feedback from the child process.
ReadFile(hReadStdout, ...);
```

But, the child process's processing the commands needs time, and I don't know how much time I should wait to get its output.
I used a loop that calls `PeekNamedPipe` to examine whether I can read from the pipe, but this method is not good for it consums a lot CPU.

The child process was not written by me and I can't modify its code.

How can I get informed when the child process has finished writing, like a hook?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use an event and have the child set it once it has written to the pipe.  The parent can then sit in WaitForSingleObject() and use very little cpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try using ReadFileEx() to read from the pipe asynchronously.

Comment: but MSDN says that anonymous pipe does not support asynchronous ipc. Still, named pipe can't be used to redirect chld process's io.

Comment: I'm confused: It also says that anonymous pipes are implemented as named pipes with a unique generated name, so they should support anything named pipes do... Anyway, when all else fails, you can use multithreading, reading from the pipe in another thread.

Comment: @Medinoc: yes, an anonymous pipe is implemented using a named pipe. However, asynchronous I/O on a named pipe requires specifying the Overlapped flag when the pipe is created. `CreateNamedPipe()` and `CreateFile()` both allow that, but `CreatePipe()` does not.